# Google chrome doesn't save changes of my code in the debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I am developing a web-application, and google-chrome started behaving weird. When I make change in a JavaScript file, after I hit refresh on the debugger - I still see the same code in the debugger, and the browser executes this old code. Why is google-chrome behaving like this and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Developer Tools, by right clicking and choosing "Inspect Element" or Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + J
2. Click the Cog icon in the bottom right of that window.
3. Choose the General Tab
4. Tick "Disable cache"

This will disable Chrome from caching (locally storing) a copy of the js file

Answer (score 1):

perhaps is a cache problem. try doing a cache refresh (ctrl-r, ctrl-f5). if you use cache.manifest file then you need to `touch` it in some way and double refresh your app for the changes to show.

Comment: Thank you for the response, indeed is a cache problem, but I solved it like @Andrew Hall explained.